# My preloader is not fading and keeps scrolling in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Am building a website now where I have used a preloader to fade and show the content but it doesn't seem to work pretty well, it's not fading and just keeps on scrolling in infinite loop, How can I achieve the fading?
My jquery version is 3.2.1
Here is the code I have used -

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });

});
```

```css
#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  background: #333 url('http://files.mimoymima.com/images/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="preloader"></div>
  <p>
    This is the page
  </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is ok. Just add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('#preloader').fadeOut(5000, function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });

});
```

```css
#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  background: #333 url('http://files.mimoymima.com/images/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="preloader"></div>
  <p>
    This is the page
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: The preloading is working perfectly now thank you very much :-) but how to delay the time of preloading , it's loading too fast , how can I achieve that?

Comment: change `'slow'` to delay time like `2000` for 2 seconds

Comment: @DustinD8 you should use one of following either `window.load` or `document.ready`

Comment: Ya ya my code is with window.load, By mistake I copied it from my fiddle. Thank you again for helping :-D